# Systemd Service not starting up my application

Tags: systemd

I am new to systemd service scripts. I am trying to start my application from systemd service scripts. My application is a process that in turn invokes multiple process that includes Qt GUI as one of its child. But the service downt starting up my application.

This is how my service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/rc.d/rc.local
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/rc.local start
SysVStartPriority=99


rc.local script looks like:

#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
sleep 5
cd /var/MINC3/apps
./PMonTsk
```

So when try to run the command "systemctl start rc-local.service", the command executes the script but doesnt invoke my application. If I replace some other QT GUI sample application in the plcae of my application in rc.local, it is working fine. Please help me on sorting this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you add

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I think it will work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for the above problem. I modified my service in the following way. It works fine after the modification.

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/rc.d/rc.local
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/rc.local start
ControlGroup=cpu:/
SysVStartPriority=99
```

Comment: `Type=forking` solved my issue